# Prestashop 1.6 add tinymce field to admin preferences

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to add a new field to Admin Preferences - a textarea field with tinymce. I've added code to AdminPreferencesController.php:

```
    $this->fields_options['contact'] = array(
        'title' =>  $this->l('Contact'),
        'icon' =>   'icon-cogs',
        'submit' => array('title' => $this->l('Save')),
    );

    $this->fields_options['contact']['fields']['PS_CONTACT_ADDITIONAL_INFO'] = array(
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'label' => $this->l('Short description'),
        'name' => 'short_description',
        'lang' => true,
        'cols' => 60,
        'rows' => 10,
        'autoload_rte' => 'rte',
        'col' => 6,
    );
```

But tinymce doesnt' appear and when I'm using HTML tags after saving they disappear. Presta strips all HTML tags.

How to allow HTML tags on this field and enable tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't just add it in a regular way. But you can implement it in a next way.
First of all, use field type `textareaLang` instead of `textarea` and add a parameter `'validation' => 'isCleanHtml'` to this field

```
$this->fields_options['contact']['fields']['PS_CONTACT_ADDITIONAL_INFO'] = array(
    'type' => 'textareaLang',
    'label' => $this->l('Short description'),
    'name' => 'short_description',
    'lang' => true,
    'cols' => 60,
    'rows' => 10,
    'col' => 6,
    'validation' => 'isCleanHtml'
);
```

Create your own script to initialize your editor. I created a script `tinymce.init.js` and put it to `js/admin/` folder

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ad = ''; // this is defenition of the external plugin path. I didn't fint how it can impact on script if it's empty but by default it it the path to your admin folder
    iso = iso_user;
    var config = {
        selector: '.textarea-autosize'
    };
    tinySetup(config);
});
```

Then include tinymce script and your own to this controller `AdminPreferencesController.php`

```
public function setMedia()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJquery();
    $this->context->controller->addJS(
        array(
            _PS_JS_DIR_.'admin/tinymce.init.js',
            _PS_JS_DIR_.'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            _PS_JS_DIR_.'admin/tinymce.inc.js'
        )
    );

    parent::setMedia();
}
```

It should implement your requirements. But don't forget that now you should call your configuration field in multilingual scope. So, add a language id to `Configuration::get()` like

`Configuration::get('PS_CONTACT_ADDITIONAL_INFO, $id_lang)` 
whenever you use it.

P.S. Bear in mind that the best solution for your goal is to create a simple module which will handle this. And far more, it is recommended way.